# Rust: async is not concurent

Tags: asynchronous, rust

[Here's the example](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/04_async_await_primer.html) from the Rust book.

```rust
async fn learn_and_sing() {
    // Wait until the song has been learned before singing it.
    // We use `.await` here rather than `block_on` to prevent blocking the
    // thread, which makes it possible to `dance` at the same time.
    let song = learn_song().await;
    sing_song(song).await;
}

async fn async_main() {
    let f1 = learn_and_sing();
    let f2 = dance();

    // `join!` is like `.await` but can wait for multiple futures concurrently.
    // If we're temporarily blocked in the `learn_and_sing` future, the `dance`
    // future will take over the current thread. If `dance` becomes blocked,
    // `learn_and_sing` can take back over. If both futures are blocked, then
    // `async_main` is blocked and will yield to the executor.
    futures::join!(f1, f2);
}

fn main() {
    block_on(async_main());
}
```

And it's says

> In this example, learning the song must happen before singing the song, but both learning and singing can happen at the same time as dancing.

But I can't get this point. I wrote a short code in Rust

```rust
async fn learn_song() -> &'static str {
    println!("learn_song");
    "some song"
}

#[allow(unused_variables)]
async fn sing_song(song: &str) {
    println!("sing_song");
}

async fn dance() {
    println!("dance");
}

async fn learn_and_sing() {
    let song = learn_song().await;
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    sing_song(song).await;
}

async fn async_main() {
    let f1 = learn_and_sing();
    let f2 = dance();
    let f3 = learn_and_sing();

    futures::join!(f1, f2, f3);
}

fn main() {
    futures::executor::block_on(async_main());
}
```

And it seems like all the async functions in the `async_main` executed synchronously.

The output is

```
learn_song
sing_song
dance
learn_song
sing_song
```

If they run asynchronously, I would expect to get something like this in my output

```
learn_song
dance
learn_song
sing_song
sing_song
```

If I add an extra call of `learn_and_sing` it would steel be printed like in a synchronous function.

**The question** Why so? Is it possible to make a real async using only `async/.await` and no threads?

Comment: `std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));` This is blocking the currently running thread, essentially blocking _all_ asynchronous control flows. I'm pretty sure Rust offers an asynchronous version of that.

Comment: This is especially noticable here as you're using a single-threaded executor (`block_on`), but it's worth noting that this can also cause sneaky issues on multi-threaded executors (like Tokio's default runtime) too. In that scenario, things would probably look fine on the surface, but you would have actually blocked an entire thread from being used for other tasks.

Comment: A good article on this topic: https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/

Comment: @JoeClay Blocking on `main()` is fine, and using a simple executor in exercises is too.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Yeah, to be clear, the blocking I'm saying is bad is the `sleep` in `learn_and_sing`. There's nothing wrong with using `block_on` as they're doing here, as that's outside the async context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like tkausl's comment states, std::thread::sleep makes the whole thread sleep, which prevents *any* code on the thread from executing during the sleeping duration. You could use [async_std::task::sleep](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/task/fn.sleep.html) in this situation, as it is an asynchronous version of the sleep function.

```rust
async fn learn_song() -> &'static str {
    println!("learn_song");
    "some song"
}

#[allow(unused_variables)]
async fn sing_song(song: &str) {
    println!("sing_song");
}

async fn dance() {
    println!("dance");
}

async fn learn_and_sing() {
    let song = learn_song().await;
    async_std::task::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    sing_song(song).await;
}

#[async_std::main] 
async fn main() {
    let f1 = learn_and_sing();
    let f2 = dance();
    let f3 = learn_and_sing();

    futures::join!(f1, f2, f3);
}
```

Comment: If you use `async-std`, use [its executor](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/attr.main.html), not the one of `futures`.  Though I would use `tokio`.